# Which of the following sentences is more formal?

Tags: word-choice

I don't know which of the following is more formal in writing.

1) I am going to give my children food, clothes , and other **things**.

1) I am going to give my children food, clothes , and other **stuffs**.

Comment: "Things" seem more formal to me, but I am no writer  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stuff" is informal, especially when used as a *de facto* pronoun.  "Stuffs" is normally used as a verb, not as a plural pronoun.

"Thing" is a standard pronoun, so it can be used in both formal and informal writing.  "Things" is a normal plural pronoun.

> I am going to give my children food, clothes, and other things.

sounds formal.  "I am going to", "give", and "children" are all formal choices of words.

> I am going to give my children food, clothes, and other stuff.

sounds informal enough to almost seem incorrect.  Using "kids" instead of "children" would make the sentence more consistently informal.  Using colorful metaphors (like "put clothes on my kids' backs" or "put food in my kids' bellies") would also be more consistently informal than "give my children <things>".

In informal speech, it is normal to use contractions for some words.  Even in informal writing, it is normal to transcribe these words using the full words.  Thus, your written "I am going to give" might be spoken informally as "I'm gonna give".

Answer (score 3):

As to which is the more formal, I think ***things* is more formal than *stuff***.

Also, stuff is already plural so doesn't need the added *s*. The sentence should be:

> I am going to give my children food, clothes and other stuff.